# In an array with numeric values, select the successive values within a range and set them all to the highest value of them

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

All of that in an associative array.

I have an array that holds as keys some IDs and as values some integers:

```
array([24]=>1620, [49]=>1620, [35]=>1622, [101]=>1623, [214]=>1630, [50]=>1638, [5]=>1640)
```

What I want to obtain is, while "LastValue - FirstValue <= 4", to set all near values to the highest of them, like this:

```
array([24]=>1623, [49]=>1623, [35]=>1623, [101]=>1623, [214]=>1630, [50]=>1640, [5]=>1640)
```

In reality is about some events which have a planned date; that planned date is stored as week number; I want to group the successive individual events within a month to the last week in that group.

So I have created this array with the IDs of events and the dates; the array is sorted ascendant by values. But I can't figured out how to group the successive individual values within a month, set them to the highest of them (last one) then pass to the next values, identify the group, set the values, etc

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So your keys are event IDs, your values are values, ... I just don't understand where are the dates? Do the values represent dates somehow? Note that your simplification of the problem is ambiguous. For instance, values `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` can come out like `5 5 5 5 5 10 10 10 10 10`, but also like `1 6 6 6 6 6 10 10 10 10`. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, the values are the week numbers, in PHP format "yW".

Comment: Is not important if the values are repeating; there can be multiple events planned in the same week. In example that I gave, we have 7 events: the first 4 events are in a span of 1 month (1620 to 1623), so all will be "moved" to the last week (1623); next is the event for 1630, which is the only one in a span of 1 month (1627 - 1630 or 1630 - 1633), no change here; then the last two events that are in a span of 1 month (1637 - 1640), "moved" to 1640.

Comment: My point was not that there will be repetitions, but where the cut-off point will be when there are different ways to do it? What if you have events in weeks 1620, 1621, 1622, 1623, 1624, 1625, 1626, 1627, 1628, 1629, 1630, ... etc. Then where do you want to make the split between the groups?

Comment: We always start with the first value and go as long as the last value is in a span of 1 month; then, the next value is the start value for the next month span; and so on. For your example, it will be: 1620, 1621, 1622, 1623 first month span, 1624, 1625, 1626, 1627, second, 1628, 1629, 1630, third, etc

Comment: Ok, I added this method to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you describe is ambiguous when you have long series of weeks without gaps. In that case there are several ways to group weeks together keeping the condition that the first and last week of the group should not be more than 4 weeks apart.

Assuming you don't expect such long series of non-interrupted week numbers, I present here an algorithm that goes backwards through the (sorted) array of events. It temporarily transforms week numbers to "absolute" week numbers, which do not reset to 1 each year, but keep increasing with one. That way the algorithm can equally find groups that cross year boundaries:

```
// Sample data
$data = array(24=>1620, 49=>1620, 35=>1622, 101=>1623, 214=>1630, 50=>1638, 5=>1640);

$last_abs_week = 99999;
$date = new DateTime();
// first week in the "absolute" week numbering:
$ref_date = new DateTime();
$ref_date->setISODate(2000, 1);
// Loop backwards:
foreach (array_reverse(array_keys($data)) as $event) {
    $week = $data[$event];
    // Get date corresponding to week number
    $date->setISODate("20" .  substr($week, 0, 2),  substr($week, 2));
    // Convert date to number of weeks since year 2000 to allow week numbers
    // to be subtracted even when belonging to different years
    $abs_week = $date->diff($ref_date)->format("%a") / 7;
    if ($abs_week < $last_abs_week - 4) {
        // Not within same group: start a new group
        $last_week = $week;
        $last_abs_week = $abs_week;
    } else {
        // In same group: assign last week of group
        $data[$event] = $last_week;
    }
}

print_r ($data);
```

Output for the sample data is:

```
Array
(
    [24] => 1623
    [49] => 1623
    [35] => 1623
    [101] => 1623
    [214] => 1630
    [50] => 1640
    [5] => 1640
)
```

#### Forward search

Here is an alternative way, where the array is scanned in the given order:

```
$first_abs_week = 0;
$group = [];
$date = new DateTime();
$ref_date = new DateTime();
$ref_date->setISODate(2000, 1);
foreach ($data as $event => $week) {
    // Get date corresponding to week number
    $date->setISODate("20" .  substr($week, 0, 2),  substr($week, 2));
    // Convert date to number of weeks since year 2000 to allow week numbers
    // to be subtracted even when belonging to different years
    $abs_week = $date->diff($ref_date)->format("%a") / 7;
    if (count($group) && $abs_week > $first_abs_week + 4) {
        $week = $data[array_pop($group)];
        foreach ($group as $prev_event) {
            $data[$prev_event] = $week;
        }
        $group = [];
        $first_abs_week = $abs_week;
    }
    $group[] = $event;
}

print_r ($data);
```

Output for the sample data is the same as for the first alternative.

Comment: I have done a few tests and it seems that the first method works exactly as I wanted; instead, the alternative one, doesn't, not even close to the first one. I will do some more tests to verify. Thanks!

Comment: The second piece of code had a bug, which I just corrected. The inner loop should not overwrite the `$event` variable of the outer loop, so I renamed that one.